# Don't understand closest pair heuristic from "The Algorithm Design Manual "

Tags: algorithm, graph-theory

There is almost exactly the same [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7216755/what-is-the-meaning-of-from-distinct-vertex-chains-in-this-nearest-neighbor-al/7216814#comment15114654_7216814). But I still don't understand, how is this heuristic working and in what sequence vertexes are passed through. Also there is a picture in a book: [image]

That shows comparison of nearest-neghbor heuristic and what I believe is a closest-pair heuristic. From the picture I may assume that on the top picture, 0 point was selected first, but on the bottom picture there was selected the leftmost or the rightmost one. Because there is nothing said about first point selection (also the closest-pair heuristic doesn't do any actions in that), I may assume that any algorithm results however good it is won't give you the bottom picture if it doesn't consider, what point to start with.

For now I just want to know, what steps closest-pair heuristic makes. A picture similar to the bottom one with numbers associated with each iteration along with explanation would be appreciated.

Here is the [link](http://www.cs.sysu.edu.cn/~lxm/DSA/textbook/Skiena.-.TheAlgorithmDesignManual.pdf) to the book taken from that post.

Answer (score 17):

I don't have the book, but it is showing a comparison of the nearest neighbor heuristic to the optimal solution for this data.  The data shown here is (-21, -5, -1, 0, 1, 3, 11).

The confusion may be between a "local" greedy algorithm and a "global" greedy algorithm (for lack of better word).  The nearest neighbor shown above is strictly local.  The "robot" starts at 0 and chooses to go to 1, because it is the closest path.  The robot is at 1, and finds the next closest point is -1.  Then the robot is at -1 and the next closest point is 3, and so on.

The closest pair is more global.  It is looking at all optimal edges at once.  So, the algorithm starts at 0 and finds four that are exactly 1 unit apart (0, 1), (1, 0), (-1, 0), and (0, -1).  It would add two distinct pairs creating the graph (-1, 0, 1).  This could be either directed or non-directed.

Then it would repeat, and notice that (1, 3) is the next smallest edge, and so on, until it arrives at the optimal solution.

The difference is that in the nearest neighbor case, the robot can only look at the neighbors of where it is currently located.  In the closest pair case, you can look at all edges to choose the smallest one.

Comment: @Gordon Do you mean to say that in the first iteration 0 is compared to all the other points, and then in the second iteration 1 (which is now part of a chain (0, 1) ) is compared to all other points and so on? Thanks.

Comment: @ChrisOdney . . . Yes, I think so.  I meant to say that one way builds the chain in one direction, so it only considers what to add to 1.  The other will build in both directions, and so consider what to add to 0 or 1.

Comment: When you say "It would add two distinct pairs creating the graph (-1, 0, 1)." you mean the robot is performing 1 -> -1 (or even 1 -> 0 -> -1)? So, the result is the same with the "local" greedy algorithm? I just want to make sure I'm getting this, since your reply looks the most appropriate found until now.

Comment: @AlessandroDiaferia . . . I'm not sure what your comment means.  The intention of that statement is that the robot is looking at extending the path in both direction, and chooses the best additional vertex for the extension.

Comment: I still don't understand the DIFFERENCE between closest pair and premature termination. Based on pseudocode, those two algorithms connect pionst in exactly same order!

Answer (score 15):

I agree this is not very clear in the book (which is a bit of a downer as the reader encounters it right away - page 7 in my edition).

I think the difficulty here is not in the *closest-pair heuristic* itself. The key is noticing that the heuristic is not itself supposed to be the solution to the problem! Only a part (arguably the most important part) of an algorithm that is never fully described in the book (probably because this is intended as a wrong algorithm). With the heuristic, you get the pairs of vertexes that should be connected, but not **the order** in which they ought to be connected. For that, something more is needed.

For completeness, here is the problem statement from the book

> *Problem*: Robot Tour Optimization
>
> *Input*: A set *S* of *n* points in the plane
>
> *Output*: What is the shortest cycle tour that visits each point in the set *S*

Now, the *closest-pair heuristic*, as defined in the book and quoted [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7216755/what-is-the-meaning-of-from-distinct-vertex-chains-in-this-nearest-neighbor-al/7216814#comment15114654_7216814), only gives you a set/list of connections, not the tour itself, and so not the required solution. To obtain the tour you would have to do something more. An overall (flawed!) solution using this strategy would look something like:

```
1) Initialize the output list of vertexes to visit as the empty list (call it RET).
2) Obtain the list of connections (vertex pairs) given by ClosestPair (let it be L)
3) If L is empty, jump to 12
4) Remove an arbitrary connection from L (call it C1).
5) Choose an arbitrary vertex from C1 (call it V1)
6) Append V1 to RET
7) Remove from L the other connection that contains V1 (call it C2)
8) Choose the other vertex from that connection (call it V2)
9) append V2 to RET
10) Set V1=V2
11) If L is not empty, jump back to 7
12) return RET
```

Or in pseudo-code

```
Alg(P): # P is the input set of points
    RET = []
    L = ClosestPairs(P)
    if(L.empty()):
        return RET
    C1 = L.getAndRemoveRandomElement()
    V1 = C1.getRandomVertex()
    RET.append(V1)
    while(!L.empty()):
        C2 = L.getAndRemoveElementContaining(V1)
        V2 = C2.getTheOtherVertex(V1)
        RET.append(V2)
        V1 = V2
    return RET
```

Comment: I still don't understand the DIFFERENCE between closest pair and premature termination. Based on pseudocode, those two algorithms connect pionst in exactly same order!

Comment: I am not sure I understand the question, but notice that `L` would be different if the heuristic was different.

Answer (score 3):

I was going through the same problem of understand this heuristic, my answer might help the others facing the same problem.

What does the robot need is a closed path which visits **all** the points and cycle backs to its **original** position. There is a statement mentioning premature termination which insists that the path should be full (visiting all points i.e.. we should not join some pair of vertices such that they create a smaller closed path).

Now going through the example below

[image: Figure 1.3]

here the by using the closest-pair heuristic we will find a path which connects all the points in a line and then connects the remaining end points with each other (-21 , 11). So whether robot starts with 0 or -21 or 11, it will be travelling the same distance (it will circle back to its starting position for next iteration). This distance will be the optimal distance.

But the above approach fails in the case below

[image: Figure 1.4]

here the closest pair path turns out to be the image on the left, while the optimal path should be the image on the right, hence the heuristic fails to give the correct solution.

Answer (score 2):

TL;DR - As I understand it, the "bad" approach connects increasingly distant unvisited points to each other directly, wasting more solder in multiple arcs and eventually connecting the last point back to the 1st point '0'.

The "better" approach moves outward from the center 1 point at a time in either direction, so still back & forth, but only laying solder between directly neighboring points along the 'number line'.

The illustrations & explanations really aren't clear in a single static image. He doesn't explain what the dotted line means (is it soldered? Is it just motion? Seems inconsistent). Agree this is frustrating to encounter so early in what's supposed to be the "clear" algorithms book ...

Both the "closest neighbor" AND "closest pair" examples seem to "hopscotch" back & forth over point 0, which is the reason given for the 1st approach being bad. He even says the 2nd approach should also alternate left-right, so how is it any better? Because you only connect directly neighboring points to each other, building up the complete line incrementally.

The "bad" example (as I understand it):

```
1. 0 connects to 1
2. 1 jumps over 0 & connects to -1
3. -1 jumps over 0 & connects to 3
4. 3 jumps over 0 & connects to -5
5. -5 jumps over 0 & connects to 11
6. 11 jumps over 0 & connects to -21
7. -21 connects back to 0, completing the cycle.
```

These "hopscotch" back & forth over 0, but don't connect the points in a straight line. You wind up w/6 distinct 'lines' of soldered connections.

The "better" closest pair example:

```
1. 0 connects to 1.
2. 0 connects to -1
3. 1 connects to 3
4. -1 connects to -5
5. 3 connects to 11
6. -5 connects to -21
7. -21 connects to 11 
8. Unstated, the robot arm apparently travels back to 0 afterward?
```

These also go back & forth over 0, but incrementally extend the existing straight line by one point at a time at each step. Instead of 6 arcs of solder, you have a single line for most of it, and then the 2nd connection of the outermost endpoints.

Answer (score 1):

I think in the top picture the start is zero so the algorithm used "local greedy" becomes inefficient,
while in the second one, the starting point is in the corners so maybe the shortest tour is from one end to the other and then returns to our starting point.
so the algorithm used is wrong and may give output that is not even close to the shortest tour of the set of points.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).